# McAfee download warning message

Tags: xls, mcafee

**I have two sites both on different server**, both sites having same source code but having different urls.
I am generating report in XLS formate, when i tried to download this report one site showing warning message but second working perfectly.
Both sites having the same code written in Classic ASP.

one site working fine for xsl file download but second showing error message.

[Screen shot:-Warning message from McAfee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3aeb.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: facing same issue, have you got any resolution?